# CD drive detected by BIOS but not by Windows

Tags: windows-10, optical-drive

The CD-ROM drive is detected in the BIOS. It says it's connected on SATA_0. It's not detected by Windows, not in my computer, not in disk management, and not in Device Manager.

I tried reconnecting the cables multiple times. I tried looking for the UpperFilters and LowerFilters entries in the registry, but there were none in the `CDROM` key.

I also wanted to try to install the firmware, but in the readme it said not to install it if the problem you're having is that it's not showing up in Windows.

My CD-ROM  drive is an LG GH24NSB0. It's connected with a SATA I cable even though the motherboard and drive support SATA III.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems there are several fixes for this problem. However, this is what fixed my specific problem.

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Uninstall everything under IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers
3. Reboot

https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-dvd-drive-shows-up-in-bios-but-not-in-windows.600107/

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm this worked for me with Windows 10 Version 1903. The drive was seen in BIOS, but not in Windows.In my case it was after adding a new SSD and moving the SATA connections for one or more existing devices.